# Function of random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

If I have a function of a discrete random variable and a continuous random variable how can I know if the function is a continuous or discrete random variable in general?

I have a case with a X ~ exponential(1) and Y ~ geometric(1/2). To find max(X,Y) do I have to compute the max of the distribution functions i.e. max(1-e^(-x), 1-(2^(-|x|-1)))?

Comment: Might be easier to answer if you give the particular case you are interested in.

Comment: In your case, the distribution of $\max(X,Y)$ has both a continuous part and a discrete part.

Comment: @Did how can I show that?

Comment: Either thinking about the events [max(X,Y)=n] for n integer and [t<max(X,Y)<t+dt] for t not an integer, in terms of X and Y; or computing the CDF.